# Styling <blockquote> in Android TextView

Tags: android, html, textview, blockquote

Is it possible to change the style of `<blockquote>` contents rendered in an Android [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)?

I am setting the text like so:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(someHtmlString));
```

In the `android:Theme.Light` theme, this renders blockquotes like normal text, but with a thin, blue, vertical line along the left-hand edge of the paragraph.

---

### Research

I have checked [the XML attributes for `TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#lattrs), but cannot find any mention of blockquote styling.  I have also checked [the source code for the theme I am using](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml), but can't find any likely-sounding attributes.

---

### Desired Style

Ideally I'd like to have control over how much the text is indented, and to apply some simple style, such as *italics* to the text in the `<blockquote>`.

Making the text *italic* could probably be done by inserting `<i>` tags inside all `<blockquote>` tags before passing the text to `Html.fromHtml()`, but this is not ideal.

Comment: How do you want the text to be displayed?

Comment: Good question - I will update the OP.